# Quick File to Hashtable in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashmap, hashtable

Given an array of key-value pairs (for example read in through ConvertFrom-StringData), is there a streamlined way of turning this into a Hashtable or similar to allow quick lookup? I.e. a way not requiring me to loop through the array and manually build up the hashtable myself.

**Example data**

```
10.0.0.1=alice.example.com
10.0.0.2=bob.example.com
```

**Example usage**

```
$names = gc .\data.txt | ConvertFrom-StringData
// $names is now Object[]
$map = ?
// $map should now be Hashtable or equivalent
echo $map['10.0.0.2'] 
// Output should be bob.example.com
```

Basically what I'm looking for is a, preferably, built-in file-to-hashtable function. Or an array-to-hashtable function.

---

***Note:*** As [@mjolnior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24459726/39321) explained, I actually got hash tables, but an array of single value ones. So this was fixed by reading the file `-raw` and hence didn't require any array to hashtable conversion. Updated the question title to match that.

Comment: So, wait, I'm confused... what's wrong with doing exactly what you did with `$names` and then just doing `$names.'10.0.0.2'` to get the desired output?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Syntax error, because $names ended up being an array of single value hash tables, instead of one hash table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convertfrom-Stringdata does create a hash table.

You need to give it the key-value pairs as a single multi-line string (not a string array)

```
$map = Get-Content -raw .\data.txt | ConvertFrom-StringData

$map['10.0.0.2']

bob.example.com
```

When you use Get-Content without the -Raw switch, you're giving ConvertFrom-StringData an array of single-line strings, and it's giving you back an array of single-element hash tables:

```
$map = Get-Content .\data.txt | ConvertFrom-StringData

$map.gettype()

$Map[0].GetType()

$map[0]



IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                   
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                   
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                                               
True     True     Hashtable                                System.Object                                                              

Key   : 10.0.0.1
Value : alice.example.com
Name  : 10.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks! That made a lot of sense, and totally worked :)

Answer (score 2):

I usually do the following to create a hashtable from a list of key/value pairs:

```
$hash = @{}
Get-Content 'C:\input.txt' | Where-Object {
  $_ -like '*=*'
} | ForEach-Object {
  $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
  $hash[$key] = $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This *might* not be what you're looking for, but it avoids converting the whole thing into a hash.

```
$content = @("10.0.0.1=alice.example.com","10.0.0.2=bob.example.com");
$content | ForEach-Object {
    $keyval = $_.split("=");
    if ($keyval[0] -eq "10.0.0.2") {
        $keyval[1]
    }
}
```

The output will be every value on the right side of the <kbd>=</kbd> where the left side matches that IP.

Comment: Sorry, no. Basically what I'm after is how to get what you have on your right side on line 1, from a file. Here you have hard-coded it into your script, but I need to read it from a file. I can do that easily with for example `ConvertFrom-StringData`, but the problem is that I end up with an array, and I'd like a hashtable so that I can do direct lookups without having to loop through it everytime.

I can of course loop through the array myself and build the table, but I'm thinking this should be a very common thing and hopefully already solved by something built-in.

Comment: I only hardcoded it to simplify my own testing. Replace that line with `$content = get-content .\data.txt` and you'll get the same array.

Comment: Oh! Didn't know the syntax for creating hash tables and arrays was so similar, hehe. My bad!